# Read from a text file into a vector

Tags: c++

I'm having a hard time seeing why my code doesn't work.  The part that's a problem is when I'm passing values from my text file into my grade variable.  I don't see why this is wrong.  Everything else with my code is fine except for that, but I included it all anyway.

```
string fileName;

cout << "Program that takes data from file and calculate\nmean and standard deviation and put it in file out.txt\n";
cout << "Enter the input file name ";
cin  >> fileName;
  double grade;
ifstream inData;

inData.open(fileName.c_str());

//  Declare vector<double> vecx
vector<double> vecx;
//  read data from input file to vector vecx,
while(inData >> grade)
{
    vecx.push_back(grade);
}


inData.close(); 
//  keep track how many elements you read from file
//  When you done with reading from file, close stream inData
```

And here is the full code in case you were interested.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string fileName;

    cout << "Program that takes data from file and calculate\nmean and standard deviation and put it in file out.txt\n";
    cout << "Enter the input file name ";
    cin  >> fileName;
      double grade;
    ifstream inData;

    inData.open(fileName.c_str());

    //  Declare vector<double> vecx
    vector<double> vecx;
    //  read data from input file to vector vecx,
    while(inData >> grade)
    {
        vecx.push_back(grade);
    }


    inData.close(); 
    //  keep track how many elements you read from file
    //  When you done with reading from file, close stream inData

    // read element by element  in vector vecx  and calculate sum;
    double sum=0;
    double average;
    for (int i=0; i < vecx.size(); i++)
        sum=sum+vecx[i];

    average=sum/(vecx.size());
    // sum divide by number of elements to find mean(average)

    //again read element by element and calculate
    //square of difference between element and mean
    //calculate sum of squares of differences
    //divide by number of elements and
    //take square root - you got the standard deviation

    sum=0;
    double variance, stdev;
    for (int i=0; i < vecx.size(); i++)
        sum=sum+(vecx[i]-average*vecx[i]-average);

    variance=sum/(vecx.size());
    stdev=sqrt(variance);

    //open output stream
    ofstream outData;
    outData.open("out.txt");
    //output  mean and standard deviation

    cout << "Average is " << average << endl;
    cout << "Standard deviation is " << stdev << endl;

    //close stream
    outData.close();
}
```

I feel like an idiot for not seeing why this isn't working...I should be able to figure this out but I haven't.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted what error you are getting, instead of simply "it's not working."

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is `vecx` empty after you read into it?

Comment: Without seeing the data file (which must be whitespace-separated **text** representing double values), *and* knowledge that the file opened successfully (which is never verified in the current source), it will not be possible to answer this accurately. Can you elaborate on the *exact* meaning of "it's not working"?

Comment: I have some guess: check you local settings, I mean that in different locals double can be provided using "." or ",". This one of possible cases that might cause wrong input from file.

Comment: Yep, vecx is empty after I read into it.  I caught the vecx[i]-average*vecx[i]-average error earlier but I didn't save that apparently...

But the main problem I have is I don't see why vecx is empty.  Everything I did seems right.

Comment: I suggest you check the file status after you open it.  Something like: `if (!inData) {cerr << "Error opening file.\n";}`

Comment: There's an error opening the file although it's in the same directory as my cpp program.

Answer (score 9):

C++ follows the normal mathematical orders of precedent.

This line:

```
sum=sum+(vecx[i]-average*vecx[i]-average);
```

looks incorrect. Multiplication happens before subtraction so it's calculating this:

```
sum=sum+((vecx[i]-(average*vecx[i]))-average);
```

but presumably you meant this:

```
sum=sum+((vecx[i]-average)*(vecx[i]-average));
```

You might be interested in seeing [the full list of precedence ordering](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: +1 This is definitely **a** problem, and in all likelihood **the** problem, assuming the data file is properly read. Sharp eye, sir.

Comment: Though having seen SShaheen's answer perhaps it was something down the line

Comment: Hard to say without knowing exactly what problem @Glassjawed is having.

Comment: @TimMB Honestly you *both* bring up valid points (and have been up-voted accordingly).

Answer (score 5):

You are never writing data out to your file. Use your `ofstream outData` instead of `std::cout`. Otherwise, you are only sending your output to the console.

```
//open output stream
ofstream outData;
outData.open("out.txt");
//output  mean and standard deviation

outData << "Average is " << average << endl;
outData << "Standard deviation is " << stdev << endl;

//close stream
outData.close();
```

Comment: Yeah this is the issue.  I wasn't getting anything passed into my vector and I didn't know why.  I should have been more clear earlier.

Comment: **EDIT** Yeah this is one issue.  The main issue I'm having however is that I'm not getting anything passed into my vector and I don't know why.  I should have been more clear earlier.

Right now it will print NaN as my values for average and stdev as a result.

Comment: Have a look at the reference for `ifstream`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ . You may find that it's not able to find the file you're providing it but you can test if it's 'bad' - i.e. failed to open the file.

Comment: Check if your input file is being opened. If it's not, maybe the file name you are giving it is incorrect. Perhaps it is a relative file path when the file does not exist in the same directory as your code file.